# Как вывести список категорий WordPress на другом движке?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

У меня есть блог на WordPress, который расположен в папке site.ru/blog/, в корне лежит интернет-магазин на другом движке. Мне надо в футере интернет-магазина вывести список всех категорий из вордпресс-блога. Как это сделать?

Comment: Просто интересно - неужели рубрики на блоге так часто меняются, что их нельзя просто прописать вручную в футере ИМ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте WP REST API. В коде футера Интернет-магазина обратитесь по адресу

```
http://blog.site.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
```

В ответ получите json, который надо декодировать и вывести списком.

Вот работающий код для получения списка категорий с моего тестового сайта:

```
$json       = file_get_contents( 'http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/categories' );
$array      = json_decode( $json, true );
$categories = $array['postlist'];

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category['link'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, не шарю в rest api.

Comment: Вам ни в чем шарить не надо. посмотрите пример тут http://test.kagg.eu/wp-json/wp/v2/categories

Comment: даже не представляю, что с этим делать дальше. попробую почитать документацию, однако я не программист, хз че из этого получится.

Comment: Если вы не программист, как вы собирались выводить список категорий? Ещё раз - никакой документации по REST API вам ни читать, ни знать не надо, в том и прелесть API. Делаете обычный curl на указанный в моём ответе url, получаете json, делаете json_decode(), и выводите на экран. Всё.

Comment: У меня есть начальные знания php и js. А решаю я все вопросы методом тыка))) Скажите, как сделать curl? Вся цепочка действий с json мне тоже не ясна.

Comment: Привел рабочий код. Сделал ещё проще, вместо curl - file_get_contents()